# Build Linphone from source for Raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, ubuntu-server, linphone, linphone-sdk

I tried to build a softphone from source in Raspberry Pi with ubuntu server OS 18.03 and following the tutorial from https://wiki.linphone.org/xwiki/wiki/public/view/Linphone/Linphone%20and%20Raspberry%20Pi/.

The problem is where I clone the code with command :

```
git clone git://git.linphone.org/linphone-desktop.git --recursive
```

It failed in cloning the linphone-sdk and externals file. Does anybody have the stable version on linphone that will not show error when compile ? It will be best if its the same version with linphone from apt. Thank You

Comment: I am not sure how your Ubuntu setup is affecting this, but I too struggle to build the new releases of Linphone for Raspberry Pi. I am using Raspbian myself and want python bindings. The latest release in the official apt repositories is 3.12. Any updates on this?

Comment: @Hans I have found a way to download the linphone-desktop source code including the linphone-sdk up to the `make` stage process. The way that I use is the clone of the linphone source code version 4.2 then clone the linphone-sdk source code separately. The linphone-sdk source code is then transferred to the linphone file. This resolves the linphone source code clone problem. But for the problem with linphone installation, I still have difficulty when installing libvpx.